# Is it possible to create a launch configuration from an EC2 running instance with node.js sdk?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

From [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/create-lc-with-instanceID.html) I learned that is possible to create a launch configuration passing the InstanceId of an actually running instance.

Sadly it only show the possibility to do that from AWS Console and from AWS CLI. I found the documentation about how to do that with the AWS SDK for Java, but nothing for Node.js.

Has anybody found any information about that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/AutoScaling.html#createLaunchConfiguration-property) says you can

I would use this function -  `createLaunchConfiguration` with param `InstanceId`.
Documentation well describes InstanceID as -

> The ID of the instance to use to create the launch configuration. The
>   new launch configuration derives attributes from the instance, with
>   the exception of the block device mapping.
>
> If you do not specify InstanceId, you must specify both ImageId and
>   InstanceType.
>
> To create a launch configuration with a block device mapping or
>   override any other instance attributes, specify them as part of the
>   same request.

Comment: Thanks that is what I was looking for. I just only checked it in EC2 SDK documentation that has a function with the same name, but it doesnt have the InstanceId param. Infact it is in an older versoin of the SDK. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I was able to help. Just one point though: If cli is like - "aws autoscale create-launch-configuration" then you should be looking at autoscale sdk (and not EC2 sdk).